# MS SQL bit variable can you Not(@a)?

Tags: c#, sql, variables

in c# i have a:

```
 a = !a
```

(if false makes it true, if true makes it false)

in sql i want to do the same with a BIT variable

something like:

```
 declare @a bit
 set @a = 1
 select @a
 set @a = not (@a)
 select @a
```

can i?

i could always do an IF, but this would "look better" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this by using a bitwise not

The ~ bitwise operator performs a bitwise logical NOT for the expression, taking each bit in turn. If expression has a value of 0, the bits in the result set are set to 1; otherwise, the bit in the result is cleared to a value of 0. In other words, ones are changed to zeros and zeros are changed to ones.

```
declare @a bit
 set @a = 0
 select @a
 set @a = ~@a
 select @a
```

make it 1

```
declare @a bit
 set @a = 1
 select @a
 set @a = ~@a
 select @a
```

Comment: ~ (Bitwise NOT) Returns the ones complement of the number.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [XOR](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/f8a2c563-efd1-47c5-81d0-1df09332cbcf) operator for that.

```
declare @a bit
set @a = 1
select @a

set @a = @a ^ 1
select @a

set @a = @a ^ 1
select @a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
set @a = @a^1
```